# Force Browser not to use cached JS file

Tags: javascript, jsp, browser

Whenever I update my JS file browser will perform operations using old JS file. I want to prevent caching of JS file.

I have used some code to prevent caching but they didn't work.

**Home.jsp**

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
%>
```

Comment: add `?1` to the file name, e.g. `<script src="gl.js?v1"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a random query string to the src

You could either do this manually by incrementing the querystring each time you make a change:

For example:

```
 "http://example.com/cool.js" + "?ts=" + new Date().getTime();
```